# How should I test for when 2 players have a total score of 20 when added together?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to kill players when together they have obtained 20 points in total.

Say 1 player had 10 and the other had 10. When I add them together they add up to 20 and they need to be killed. How should I perform checks and execute `/kill` if necessary, using commands?

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

```
scoreboard players operation #sum myScoreboard = @a[tag=player1] myScoreboard
scoreboard players operation #sum myScoreboard += @a[tag=player2] myScoreboard
execute if score #sum myScoreboard matches 20 run say Player 1 and Player 2 have a total score of 20
```

### Explanation

Line 1:

```
scoreboard players operation #sum myScoreboard = @a[tag=player1] myScoreboard
```

Line 1 copies the score of Player 1 to another container. To do this, a fake player, `#sum`, is used. The objective this fake player belongs to does not matter.

Using the `scoreboard players operation` command, `#sum`'s score is set equal to Player 1's score using the `=` operator.

Player 1 is referenced by the target selector, `@a[tag=player1]`. Research target selectors for more information.

---

Line 2:

```
scoreboard players operation #sum myScoreboard += @a[tag=player2] myScoreboard
```

Line 2 adds the score of Player 2 to `#sum`. Similarly to line 1, `scoreboard players operation` is utilized, except this time, the `+=` operator is used instead of `=`.

---

Line 3:

```
execute if score #sum myScoreboard matches 20 run say Player 1 and Player 2 have a total score of 20
```

Line 3 tests if the score of `#sum` matches 20. If it passes, "Player 1 and Player 2 have a total score of 20" will be displayed in chat.